# Receive notifications in Android App (Flutter) application without using Firebase

Tags: flutter

I just started learning Flutter.
Now I want to make a simple app that when user A touches the button, a default message will be sent to user B
I want a notification to be displayed when the app is closed and a message to be displayed when the app is entered.

1-1 I made the backend with Laravel and Pusher, but I don't know how to receive and send notifications on the mobile side with the API in real time.
2- Is it possible to do it without using only Flutter and without needing Laravel and...?

thank you